# Is there any public database for financial transactions

Tags: data-request, finance

I want to use the R language to do data mining for anti-money laundering. But do do this I first need a dataset of transactions.
Is such a set available?

Comment: I'm working in similar area and I'm interested too in open data for AML, KYC etc.

Answer (score 1):

[IFF - Illicit Financial Flows (PDF) - Report of the High Level Panel
on Illicit Financial Flows from Africa](https://web.archive.org/web/20170126013625/http://www.uneca.org/sites/default/files/PublicationFiles/iff_main_report_26feb_en.pdf) has money laundering data, though you'll have to pull it out of the PDF.

[Search FinCen Case Examples for type of "Money Laundering"](https://www.fincen.gov/resources/law-enforcement/case-examples?field_tags_investigation_target_id=680) .

[Financial Intelligence Unit India has reports about their cooperation with domestic and international law enforcement agencies](https://data.gov.in/catalog/financial-intelligence-unit-india-cooperation-domestic-and-international-law-enforcement).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the OCCRP [Azerbaijani laundromat](https://www.occrp.org/en/azerbaijanilaundromat/raw-data/) transactions data retrieved from Danske Bank. The data is [available as json](https://cdn.occrp.org/projects/azerbaijanilaundromat/interactive/dkdata.json) (13MB), too bad they didn't provide easy link to a compressed file.

Answer (score -3):

Use the bitcoin log of transactions.